# Output signal is being attenuated after the Biquad filter direct Form 1, why?

Tags: filters, analog-to-digital

Thought this would deserve a separate post on its own.

What's going on is that I finally got my low pass digital filter working on the [STM32H753ZI](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA841CA841&sxsrf=ALeKk0181J_yj10LYaGo5FVNDbOKMr78Qg%3A1602789035623&ei=q56IX_2-JZH5tAbGzr2YAw&q=stm32H753zi&oq=stm32H753zi&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzIECCMQJzICCAAyBAgAEB4yBAgAEB4yBAgAEB46BAgAEEdQvxhYvxhg9xxoAHACeACAAWCIAWCSAQExmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi9wPi4prfsAhWRPM0KHUZnDzMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) using the [PMODI2S2](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/reference-manual) peripheral and I noticed the output signal is extremely low ~340mVpp this is after the biquad filtering. If I take out the low pass filtering the output signal then raises to around ~600mVpp.

What's causing this phenomenon? The digital filter bode plot says the gain from very low frequencies up to the cut off is 0dB so I dont understand whats going on. The only thing I can think of is the biquad filter is causing an attenuation perhaps?

Analog Filter: $$ LPF_{Analog}=\frac{3.94e07}{s^2+8889s+3.94e07}$$

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JCTN.png)

Digital Filter: using tustin $$ LPF_{Digital}=\frac{0.00102z^2 +0.002041z+0.00102}{z^2-1.908z+0.9116}$$

[image]

Pictures:

Input signal(yellow) from wave gen and output signal(green) after the Biquad filter
[image]

Input signal(yellow) from wave gen and output signal(green) passthrough with the peripheral no digital processing
[image]

Bode plot from Oscilloscope with the biquad filter:
[image]

CODE:

```
#define ARM_MATH_CM7

#include "main.h"

#include "arm_math.h"


void init_Clock(void);
void init_I2S(void);
void init_Debugging(void);
void init_Interrupt(void);
void init_SpeedTest(void);

int32_t RxBuff[4];
int32_t TxBuff[4];
uint8_t TC_Callback = 0;
uint8_t HC_Callback = 0;

char uartBuff[8];
 float32_t iir_coeffs[5] = {0.00102f, 0.002041f, 0.00102f, 1.908f, -0.9116f}; //B0, B1, B2, A1, A2
float32_t iir_mono_state[4];

float32_t Rx_Buff_f[4];
float32_t Rx_Buff_f_out[4];


arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 monoChannel;


void DMA1_Stream0_IRQHandler(void) {

    if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF0)) != 0){
        DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF0;
        TC_Callback = 1;
    }

    else if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_HTIF0)) != 0){
         DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF0;
         HC_Callback = 1;

    }
}

int main(void) {

    init_Clock();
    init_I2S();
    //init_Debugging();
    init_Interrupt();
    //init_SpeedTest();
    arm_biquad_cascade_df1_init_f32(&monoChannel, 1, iir_coeffs, iir_mono_state);

  while (1)
  {

      if (HC_Callback == 1){

         // GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS3_HIGH;

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
              Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
          }

          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, Rx_Buff_f, Rx_Buff_f_out, 2);

          for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                TxBuff[i] = (int32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
            }

          HC_Callback = 0;

      } else  if (TC_Callback == 1){


        //  GPIOA->BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR3_LOW;


          for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
               Rx_Buff_f[i] = (float32_t)RxBuff[i];
            }

                  arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(&monoChannel, &Rx_Buff_f[2], &Rx_Buff_f_out[2], 2);

                  for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++){
                        TxBuff[i] =  (int32_t)Rx_Buff_f_out[i];
                    }



          TC_Callback = 0;

      }



  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the filter with a gain of 1.  I.e set b0 to 1, b1, b2, a1, a2 to 0. ?

This looks more like a data format issue

Comment: Tried with all the coefficients to 1, it breaks the thing theres no output, however I noticed there's a filter network on the I2S peripheral directly, this could be the reasoning. https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/pmod/pmodi2s2/pmodi2s2_sch.pdf

Comment: setting all coefficients to 1 is not a good idea...

Comment: To convert your filter to a DC gain of 1, set b0 to 1 AND b1, b2, a1, a2 to 0.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I misread that, trying it now.

Comment: @Ben interesting its 600mV now

Comment: Have you tried your digital filter in Matlab ?Perhaps there's a bug in the conversion from Laplace to Z.

Comment: @Ben well I am confused as to why its only 600mV and not 1Vpp as my input and besides just generating a bode plot, no I have not

Comment: The DC Gain of your IIR filter is about -53 dB. Try it in Matlab

Comment: @Ben Really? I get 1 for my DC again using a step response.

Comment: @Ben and does -53dB really make sense? 10^(-53/20) = 0.00223872113. 1Vpp input * 0.00223872113 = 0.00223872113V however I am getting 300mV?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @Pllsz [You already know](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/527608/95619) why the filter doesnt respond well to low frequencies.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen This is true, however this was posted the same time and kinda went its own way. I posted what you said here as well

Comment: Like I said, your comment about your coefficients is misleading.

you inverted the sign of a1 and a2, which is ok. However, the comment should mention that.

Comment: @Ben Ill take fault there. However what I posted about the I2S Peripheral device having a band pass filter, that could cause the attenuation then right? What doesnt make sense to me right now is that having the biquad have a gain of just 1 gives me an output voltage of 600mV, that make sense due to the RC bandpass network, however when using my digital filter is further attenuated to 340mV? My filter should have a DC gain of 1 so I should still see 600mV ?